# Directive Scope Boolean Attribute

Tags: angularjs-directive

I want to use the presence (or absence) of a attribute as a boolean in my directive.  For example:

```
<foo bar baz></foo>
```

Where in my controller I have the following:

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
    if $scope.bar === null {
        alert("Bar Present");
    }
    if $scope.baz === null {
        alert("Baz Present");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in the above bar and baz are not set at all on the $scope.  I'd expect to see a null or an explicit 'undefined' there. But the $scope just doesn't have bar or baz properties.

Comment: Note: I don't care what I've got to do in my controller or my link function; but I *do* care about the syntax of the directive.  It should be as simple as including or not including the attribute, rather than setting it equal to an empty string or "true".  I'm also not a huge fan of directly accessing the attrs on the $element (although I am currently solving the problem that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working code sample for what I think you want](http://plnkr.co/edit/tWJ7gvZ7oMRZAmvRfVrP)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', [function(){

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<div>directive test</div>',
  link: function(scope, el, attrs){
    if(attrs.bar !== undefined) { el[0].innerText = 'bar'; }
    if(attrs.baz !== undefined) { el[0].innerText = el[0].innerText + ' baz'; }
  }
};

}]);

  <body>
    <my-directive bar baz></my-directive>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had been hoping for a result using just the controller, but it makes sense that it'd have to be earlier in the linking process.

Comment: yea, anything that touches the html(dom) i use the link function, it was very hard for me at first letting go of the 'jquery' way of doing things, but angular is well worth the effort

Comment: Well, I hadn't really expected it to work like jquery...just didn't grok where I had access to the attrs in a directive.